# How to console command through VNC (Theoretical)

Tags: php, vnc

We would like to know that, is there a way to connect to a Windows or a Linux machine with VNC, assuming that all necessary applications are installed on those Windows or Linux machine, using - here comes the fantasy - PHP and send various console commands?

To wrap it up we would like to use VNC and PHP to connect to the machine and send console commands. How can we do this?

As this question is theoretical, I accept theoretical answers also.
Thanks

Comment: May you want to take a look at this: https://wiki.amahi.org/index.php/WebVNC
It's a java applet VNC Viewer

Comment: Why use `VNC` and not `SSH`?

Comment: We have a problem with SSH which is not about SSH actually, that is why we wanted to try VNC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. There's a socket interface in PHP and there's nothing stopping you implementing RFB in PHP.

How you plan to run commands I don't know, because RFB doesn't cater for that.

Also, the usual answer of "don't do it yourself, use a library" doesn't apply here, because I highly doubt anyone's written an VNC client in pure PHP. It's an insane language. Can you really not shell out to a Java binary or something to do the heavy lifting..?